# Implementation of modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm currently working on an e-commerce site using React and TypeScript.
I'm in the process of implementing a product image modal.
When the image modal is displayed, if I zoom in, it expands to the full screen.

Is it possible to implement the modal so that only the image modal can be enlarged without enlarging the back screen?

Comment: a codesandbox would help us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many readymade components available to handle this.
[react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch) will be a good choice for this. A demo is availble [here](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/examples-big-image--big-image).

Comment: Thank you.
Thanks to react-zoom-pan-pinch for the solution!